# Softlayer api to get cancellation reclaim status

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Please help me to get the softlayer api to get the reclaim status of the cancelled Item such as hosts, subnet, vlan etc.

`billing_svc.get(Id=billingItemId)` response does not have any field to know the status of cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how did you cancel the item, normally all the reclaims have a cancelation ticket you can get the cancellation ticket. you can get the ticket using the following object mask

```
billing_svc.get(Id=billingItemId, mask=mask[cancellationRequests[ticket]] )
```

The ticket should contain information about if the billing item has been reclaimed or not.

Let me know if this works for you

Regards